# AN country code in maxmind database, what country does it refer to?

Tags: country-codes, maxmind

Selecting distinct(country) from my maxmind database i found country with code "AN", that is not in list here:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/codes/iso3166

and on wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

For which country it can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm
This is Netherlands Antilles